# Magento 2 - How to create post form in admin?

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, magento-2.1.1

I want to create a post form by using UI component, it has 2 selectbox, 1 submit button and URL to submit.

Currently, I use **.xml** layout and template **.phtml** to render html but I want use UI component because it look beautiful and professional.

What can I do? Thanks,

Comment: What Magento 2 version you are using?

Comment: I'm using Mage 2.1.1

Comment: @HenryBui have you found any alternative?

Comment: @Knight017 not yet at that time. And I'm not working on Magento anymore.

Answer (score 1):

You can refer sample provided my magento itself to create a form in ui-component

https://github.com/magento/magento2-samples/tree/master/sample-module-form-uicomponent

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Ui/etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">sampleform_form.sampleform_form_data_source</item>
            <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">sampleform_form.sampleform_form_data_source</item>
        </item>
        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Sample Form</item>
        <item name="layout" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="type" xsi:type="string">tabs</item>
        </item>
    </argument>

    <dataSource name="sampleform_form_data_source">
        <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
            <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">Magento\SampleForm\Model\DataProvider</argument>
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">sampleform_form_data_source</argument>
            <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">entity_id</argument>
            <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
        </argument>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/provider</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </dataSource>

    <fieldset name="sample_fieldset">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Sample Fieldset</item>
            </item>
        </argument>

        <!-- This field represents form id and is hidden -->
        <field name="entity_id">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">sampleform</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>

        <!-- This field has data type 'text' and standard 'input' form element and looks like input -->
        <field name="title">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Some text</item>
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">sampleform</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>

        <!-- This field has data type 'text'
        and override standard 'input' form element's tempate and constructor by custom ones -->
        <field name="color">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <!--component constructor-->
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_SampleForm/js/form/element/color-select</item>
                    <!--main template for form field that renders elementTmpl as a child template-->
                    <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/form/field</item>
                    <!--customized form element template that will show colors-->
                    <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">Magento_SampleForm/form/element/color-select</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Autumn colors</item>
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">sampleform</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
     </fieldset>
 </form>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I just want create a submit form to URL and don't use Model or interactive with database.